# PySpark job only partly running

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark script that I am running locally with `spark-submit` in Docker. In my script I have a call `toPandas()` on a PySpark DataFrame and afterwards I have various manipulations of the DataFrame, finishing in a call to `to_csv()` to write results to a local CSV file.

When I run this script, the code after the call to `toPandas()` does not appear to run. I have log statements before this method call and afterwards, however only the log entries before the call show up on the `spark-submit` console output. I have thought that maybe this is due to the rest of the code being run in a separate executor process by Spark, so the logs don't show on the console. If this is true, how can I see my application logs for the executor? I have enabled the event log with `spark.eventLog.enabled=true` but this seems to show only *internal* events, not my actual application log statements.

Even if the assumption about executor logs above is true or false, I don't see the CSV file written to the path that I expect (`/tmp`). Further, the history server says `No completed applications found!` when I start it, configuring it to read the event log (`spark.history.fs.logDirectory` for the history server, `spark.eventLog.dir` for Spark). It does show an incomplete application, the only complete job listed there is for my `toPandas()` call.

How am I supposed to figure out what's happening? Spark shows no errors at any point, and I can't seem to view my own application logs.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `toPandas()` to convert your spark dataframe to your pandas dataframe, it's actually a heavy action because it will pull all the records to the driver.

Remember that Spark is a distributed computing engine and it's doing the parallel computing. Therefore your data will be distributed to different node and it's completely different to pandas dataframe, since pandas works on single machine but spark work in cluster. You can check this post: [why does python dataFrames' are localted only in the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690443/why-does-python-dataframes-are-localted-only-in-the-same-machine)

Back to your post, actually it covers 2 questions:

1. Why there is no logs after `toPandas()`: As mentioned above, Spark is a distributed computing engine. The event log will only save the job details which appear in Spark computation DAG. Other non Spark log will not be saved in spark log, if you really those log, you need to use external library like `logging` to collect the logs in driver.
2. Why there is no CSV saved in `/tmp` dir: As you mentioned that when you check the event log, there is a an incomplete application but not a failed application, I believe you dataframe is so huge that you collection has not finished and your transformation in pandas dataframe has even not yet started. You can try to collect few record, let's say `df.limit(20).toPandas()` to see if it works or not. If it works, that means your dataframe that converts to pandas is so large and it takes time. If it's not work, maybe you can share more about the error traceback.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I have noticed that `spark-submit` exits with code 137, but no error is thrown. Note that I am running in a container on my laptop. Not sure if memory is an issue here.

Comment: @Boon Docker container exit code `137` is exactly triggered by out-of-memory, that means you data is very large.